# Replace existing existing pdf form field with new form field at the same palce

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, pdf, itext

I need to replace a check box in existing pdf with new check box using ItextSharp.

While reading the Pdf how do I know the location of form field which I am reading.

rectangle measures and page information (If the form field I am reading now is in page number 6).

Precisely what I want to know is how to know existing form field location while reading?
Can anyone provide some sample code on finding location and page.

Why am I trying to replace existing pdf? you can find the reason here..

[Unable to print Check Boxes in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265592/unable-to-print-check-boxes-in-pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a PdfReader, you can easily access the AcroFields of the reader which hold the coordinates of all fields:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFilename);
AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
IList<FieldPosition> positions = acroFields.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);
```

You get a list of FieldPosition elements (each containing a page number and a rectangle) because a PDF form field may have multiple visualizations. In your case the list most likely contains but one element.

The method documentation of GetFieldPositions is a bit out of date, though. ;)